# Create new categorical variable based on multiple binary columns

Tags: python, pandas, variables, binary, categorical-data

I have a data frame with many binary variables and I would like to create a new variable with categorical values based on many of these binary variables

My dataframe looks like this

```
gov_winner    corp_winner    in part
        1              0           0
        0              1           0
        0              0           1
```

I variable I would like to create is called `winning_party` and would look like this

```
gov_winner    corp_winner    in part    winning_party
        1              0           0             gov
        0              1           0            corp
        0              0           1         in part
```

I started trying the following code but haven't had success yet:

```
 harrington_citations = harrington_citations.assign(winning_party=lambda x: x['gov_winner'] 
 == 1 then x = 'gov' else x == 0)
```

Using anky_91's answer I get the following error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

Comment: There are only columns filled by `1` and `0` ?

Comment: `df@df.columns` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dot product:

```
df.assign(Winner_Party=df.dot(df.columns))
#df.assign(Winner_Party=df @ df.columns)

   gov_winner  corp_winner  in_part Winner_Party
0           1            0        0   gov_winner
1           0            1        0  corp_winner
2           0            0        1      in_part
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the error I got. A problem may be that the actual data frame I am working with has many variables not involved in this new variable I am working to create. Thanks.

Comment: I can make a df with just the variables I am using to create this new variable and see if your answer works...

Comment: @GrahamStreich May be you have columns which doesnt only have 1 and 0 , filter such columns out and try

Answer (score 3):

How about `idxmax`, notice this will only select the first max , you have multiple cell equal to 1 per row, you may want to try Jez's solution

```
df['Winner_Party']=df.eq(1).idxmax(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is always only one `1` per rows use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html), also you can filter only `1` and `0` columns before:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.isin([0,1,'0','1']).all()].astype(int)
df['Winner_Party'] = df1.dot(df1.columns)
```

But if there is multiple `1` per rows and need all matched values add separator and then remove it :

```
df['Winner_Party'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')

print (df)
   gov_winner  corp_winner  in part Winner_Party
0           1            0        0   gov_winner
1           0            1        0  corp_winner
2           0            0        1      in part
```